# Hyphenation in BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, hyphenation, bst

How to disable hyphenation in BibTeX?

I know you can disable hyphenation in `.bib` file, but is there any method to disable line splitting from `.bst` file or main `.tex` file.

Thanks

Comment: Hello. Welcome to tex.SE. Your question may actually be a lot easier to answer, if you gave some more details about your use-case, esp. what you want to achieve and why. The reasons for this is that for bibliographies much depends on the style you use and the method you use to implement and create your bibliography. Consider giving us a minimal working example (MWE) to demonstrate your specific issue.

Comment: if you set your bibliograhy `\raggedright` (settable in the main tex document) then it won't hyphenate